# Duplicate an entire Wordpress site in the same domain

Tags: wordpress

I have a live site built in Wordpress at www.site.com/name1.

The client wants a new theme.  I've heavily modified the current theme with custom code and will need to do so with the new theme, all without interrupting the live site, so this wont be as simple as moving the site from one theme to another.  Therefore I *think* I need to create a duplicate of the site at www.site.com/name2 because the content will all be the same.  Doing this will give me a place to work on the redesign.

What is the best way to go about doing this?  Should I have both use the same DB or not?  When I get ready to go live should i simple redirect the domain to /name2 or move everything at /name2 to /name1?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same Data you can use the same DB but there is somes Options Tables dans Meta tables in the Wordpress DB, then if you change parameters on one site it will affect the other.

If you just recode the Theme without touching anything in the configuration you can use the same DB to test your theme with valid datas, but if you think you'll have to change paramaters i would prefer duplicate the Production DB to a Test DB to secure the production Website.

When you go live you'll just have to move your theme to the production website and copy your Option and Meta Tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you're at a point where you're having clients, you should definitely develop locally. This will free you from the trouble of mistakingly messing up the production site.

1. Install Apache, MySQL and PHP on your own machine.
2. Copy database and files from production.
3. Change anything you'd like without exposing it to the Internet.
4. Upload your new, tailor-suited theme to production when it's ready to go live.